# Modelling returns in the real world measure with or without drift

Tags: brownian-motion, log-returns, regulatory-formula

What I would like to discuss is the following. I don't think that this is a pure duplicate, so I would be happy about comments:

On one hand it is reasonable to model log-returns as Gaussian:
$$
\log(S_{t+\Delta}/{S_t}) = \sigma B_{\Delta t}    \tag{1}
$$
with a Gaussian random variable $B_{\Delta t} \sim N(0,\Delta t)$.

On the other hand as e.g. in the calculations of the equivalent Gaussian volatility [for PRIIPS](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26125/how-is-the-formula-for-the-vev-var-equivalent-volatility-in-the-priip-document) we model
$$
S_{t+\Delta} = S_t \exp \left( - \sigma^2/2 \Delta + \sigma \left( B_{t+ \Delta t} - B_{t } \right) \right),
$$
and thus
$$
\log(S_{t+\Delta}/{S_t}) =  - \sigma^2/2 \Delta + \sigma \left( B_{t+ \Delta t} - B_{t } \right), \tag{2}
$$
which leads to a non-centered Gaussian.

I know that $(2)$ is the natural model if we want to use the SDE
$$
dS_t = \sigma S_t dB_t,
$$
whose discretized version is
$$
S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t } \approx \sigma S_t \left( B_{t+ \Delta t} - B_{t } \right),
$$
which can be reformulated as 
$$
\frac{S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t }}{S_t} \approx \sigma \left( B_{t+ \Delta t} - B_{t } \right).
$$

So how does all this fit together? In risk management we often assume that log-returns are Gaussian $(1)$ and the regulator of PRIIPS assumes that arithmetic returns are approximately Gaussian? How can we interpret the correction term intuitively in $(2)$?

EDIT: Hopefully doing the right maths:

In setting (A) which gives us equation (1) we have the following stochastic model:
$$
S_{t + \Delta t} = S_t \exp \left( \sigma (B_{t + \Delta t} - B_t)  \right)
$$
then for the log return $R_t$ we have
$$
R_t = \log\left(S_{t + \Delta t}/S_t \right) = \sigma (B_{t + \Delta t} - B_t).
$$
Then $R_t$ has a Gaussian distribution with expectation $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 \Delta t$.

Setting (B):
$$
S_{t + \Delta} = S_t \exp \left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \Delta t + \sigma (B_{t + \Delta t} - B_t)  \right)
$$
and get for
$\log(S_{t + \Delta}/S_t)$ again something Gaussian with expectation $-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \Delta t$ and variance $\sigma^2 \Delta t$.

For $\Delta t$ small (one or just a couple of days) the difference is negligible but for longer terms (e.g. recommended holding periods) we have to model many $\Delta t$ steps leading to a larger term there. So there is a difference on the long run.

Comment: $(2)$ is more theoretically correct. However, since $\sigma^2/2 \Delta$ is usually small, you can ignore it. Note also that $$\ln(S_{t_\Delta}/S_t) \approx \frac{S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t }}{S_t} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t }}{S_t} \right)^2 \approx \frac{S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t }}{S_t} - \frac{1}{2}E\left(\left(\frac{S_{t+ \Delta t} - S_{t }}{S_t} \right)^2\right).$$

Comment: For us non-illuminati, can you briefly explain what PRIIPS is and why anyone would care about it?

Comment: @DavidAddison this is some regulation what an information document for the sale of packaged retail investment and insurance products  has to contain. This applies to unit linked insurance and later to mutual funds.

Comment: @Gordon or is it simply that $\sigma$ in one case is just a constant and in the other case it is $\sigma(S_t) = \sigma S_t$ and if I assume that volatility is proportional to the price (and then I can interpret it as percentage vol) then I need version (2)?

Comment: @Gordon in your equaton the last term is equla to the Ito correction term $1/2 \sigma^2 dt$, right?

Comment: Yes. The last term equals to Ito's correction. In both cases, the volatility is $\sigma S_t$. Note that the term $\sigma^2/2\Delta$ is generally small, so you can ignored it. For example, for $\sigma = 20\%$ and $\Delta = 1/252$, then $\sigma^2/2\Delta=0.00007937$.

Comment: @Gordon you are right about the volailtiy. Please see my edit. if the difference is small for small times then it does not matter, but do we get explosions for large times if we don't apply the correction term?

Comment: Our assumption is for small $\Delta$. Note that, for bigger $\Delta$, $\frac{S_{t+\Delta}-S_t}{S_t}$ may no longer be small, then the above approximation can not be used at all.

Comment: @Gordon the approximation is clear... But what about explosions?

Comment: @Richard: I do not understand what you mean for explosion. Is there a mathematical definition?

Comment: @Gordon I will post something about explosions tomorrow. And I am quite sure that this is not (!) the problem anyways.

Comment: Note that, for setting (A), $E(S_{t+\Delta} \mid S_t) = S_te^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \Delta}$. If $\Delta$ is sufficiently large, then $E(S_{t+\Delta} \mid S_t)$ can be exploded, that is, approaches to $\infty$.

Comment: @Gordon I answered myself to facilate this discussion. In short: the processes do not explode either way but without drift correction we introduce a spurious positive drift in setting (A). Maybe this was clear for you from the start :)

Answer (score 2):

After editing my queston several times I decided to write an answer.

In setting (B) we have the Ito correction term. As Gordon mentions this makes the expected value vanish.

In setting (A) we introduce a positive drift of the size $\sigma^2 \Delta t/2$ even if we stay in discrete time. It is there.

The following code illustrates this in R. The setting `mu=0` corresponds to (A) and `mu = -sigma^2/2`to (B).
In A after 10 years and using 1000 paths we have an average of 12% gain which is what we can expect if we have the drift of $0.15^2/2$ ($15\%$ vol in the example below) for 10 years  which equals $11.25 \%$ (!)

[image: sample paths drift not corrected]
In B we have -3% which I think is just a sampling error and it should be zero. In a second run I got the 0 expected growth.

[image: sample paths drift corrected]

Both processes reach similar maxima and do not explode.

Bottom line: on the long run not accounting for the drift correction will lead to overestimates of your performance ... which is a basic point in stochastic analysis.

```
S_0 = 100
nr_paths = 1000
delta_t = 1/250 # nr steps per year
nr_years = 10
sigma = 0.15

mu = 0 
#mu = -sigma^2/2

paths = matrix(S_0, nrow = nr_paths, ncol = nr_years/delta_t)
dBt = matrix(rnorm(nr_paths*(nr_years/delta_t-1), mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = nr_paths, ncol = nr_years/delta_t-1)

for (i in 2: (nr_years/delta_t)) {
  paths[,i] = paths[,i-1]*exp(mu*delta_t + sigma*sqrt(delta_t)*dBt[,i-1]) 
}
plot( paths[1,], type="n", ylim = range(paths), main = paste("Drift =", toString(mu))) 

for(i in 1:nr_paths) {
  lines( paths[i,], col = rgb(0,0,1,0.05) )
}

lines( apply(paths, 2, mean), col ="red")
tail(apply(paths, 2, mean))
```

EDIT: one more additional thougt:

Setting (A) (no drift correction) leads to
$$
E[\log(S_t/S_u)|\mathcal{F_u}] = 0
$$ 
thus the expectation of the (conditional) logreturn is 0, while
Setting (B) drift correction as in PRIIPS leads to
$$
E[\frac{S_t-S_u}{S_u}|\mathcal{F_u}] = 0
$$ 
thus the expectation of the (conditional) arithmetic return is zero. In this setting the price $S_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: fyi. you can set the colour in matplotlib to be an rgba colour -> set it to something like `(r,g,b,10/nr_paths)` and your plot will be much nicer.

Comment: Didn't realise it was R at first. Just add do `col = rgb(0,0,1,0.05)` to the bit where you plot the paths.

Comment: @will thanks for this advice. The plots were just quck sketches but with your input it was really easy to improve them.

Comment: yah i know, but such an easy change for much nicer plots!